# Running Spark job on YARN

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager

I am trying to utilise all the resources which I have on the cluster to run the Spark job. I have Cloudera Manager installed on all of the nodes. This is the command which I use to submit the job.

```
spark-submit --master yarn 
             --deploy-mode cluster 
             file:///[spark python file]
             file://[app argument 1]
             file://[app argument 2]
```

During the execution I receive following error:

```
diagnostics: Application application_1450777964379_0027 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1450777964379_0027_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
```

Any ideas how to fix it will be much appreciated.

**EDIT 1**
The machine where Spark is installed is not accessible by WEB UI I tried to download the sources and read little bit more about the exception.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Job | Description                                        | 
------------------------------------------------------------
| 0   | saveAsTextFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2 | 
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you have permissions to save the file in your filesystem?

Comment: As it is a cluster, on each machine I have created the supergroup and each user in that group has read/write permission to the folder where the output should be written

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://github.com/hortonworks/spark-native-yarn/issues/7),

> If the path starts with file:// or hdfs://, the path becomes ile:// or dfs://. If the path is absolute the first slash is removed.
>
> There is no particular reason for it and needs to be fixed.

Try using an absolute path instead of `file://`

Comment: I saw this thread, but I got absolutely same results nothing new, the error description is the same

Comment: I would advise you to use the Spark mailing list then. They can probably provide more help than SO community (I doubt this thread will have other answers unless someone puts a bounty on it) http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/